# Return a value within a json array (converted to python) if it equals another value

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I hope everyone is fine and in great health!
I have a little question:

I have json strings with these values

```
{"ps":"Era 7"}
{"programName":"Era 1","programId":"1001"}
{"programName":"Era 2","programId":"1002"}
{"programName":"Era 3","programId":"1003"}
{"programName":"Era 4","programId":"1004"}
{"programName":"Era 5","programId":"1005"}
{"programName":"Era 6","programId":"1006"}
{"programName":"Era 7","programId":"1007"}
```

What I need to achieve is to return the corresponding "programId" value of the "programName" value when "programName" equals to "ps" value.
For instance, if "ps" is Era7, then I need "programId" value "1007", if it is "Era 2", to get "1002" and so on!
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Please add the language you're using as a tag.

Comment: Hi, it's json data converter to python.

Comment: That's not a dictionary; that's eight separate dictionaries, only one of which can be accessed later because you didn't keep a reference to any of the rest.

Comment: OK, that's edited. It's json data that I'd like to extract certain values by conditions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have those dictionaries already extracted from a JSON and have them stored in a list...

You can simply loop through all the dictionaries comparing the "programName" values to "ps" for each dictionary, then return the "programId" of those which match.

```
target = {'ps': 'Era 7'}
dicts  = [
{"programName":"Era 1","programId":"1001"},
{"programName":"Era 2","programId":"1002"},
{"programName":"Era 3","programId":"1003"},
{"programName":"Era 4","programId":"1004"},
{"programName":"Era 5","programId":"1005"},
{"programName":"Era 6","programId":"1006"},
{"programName":"Era 7","programId":"1007"}
]
for d in dicts:
    if d['programName'] == target['ps']:
        return d['programId']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This output is already converted to a python dictionary with the loads converter. The whole output is called rds = json.loads(data.decode("utf8", "ignore")). so ps is also part of the output.